# Is it correct for services to be dependent on components/directives that consume it in Angular

Tags: angular

In my project, I need to have to [some tabs](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/). However, I can't use something like what's offered in angular material because the site is full of this pattern, and each one has different styling and different structure. So, I want to have a punch of directives that give me **only** the functionality but leaves styling for me. Something like [Angular Material CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk).

So, I've created the following directives:

- `TabList`: to hold the list of `tabItem`s.
- `TabItem`: for every tab link/button.
- `TabPanel`: for the content of every tab.

#### The problem:

But now I need to manage things like moving focus, setting active tab, etc. And I'm doing that using a service. Inside that service, however, I need to access those elements (directives hosts). So I'm having a situation where directives depend on the service to apply their functionality whereas the service needs to access those directives on initialization.

This is how it looks like:

```
.....
export class TablistDirective {
    // Injecting the service
    private tabsService = inject(TabsService);
    // Getting the host element
    private host = inject(ElementRef)

    // Initializing service property inside the directive
    ngOnInit(): void {    
        this.tabsService.tablistElement = this.host.nativeElement;
    }
       
}

// THE SAME HAPPENS WITH OTHER DIRECTIVES
```

#### The question:

1. Is it okay to initialize a service property in a directive/component that depends on that service?
2. Is that the right way to implement the tabs functionality? If not, how can I achieve that in a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance. Feel free to ask for clarification in the comments.